# In what circumstances can malloc_trim(0) cause a crash?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free, brk

I have a piece of code where I am using `malloc_trim(0)` to release any unused memory back to the system.
But very intermittently I am see that it causes a crash. Backtraces below:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  mtrim (pad=0, av=0xffff8eebf9f8 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4771
4771                INTERNAL_SIZE_T size = chunksize (p);

#0  mtrim (pad=0, av=0xffff8eebf9f8 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4771
#1  __malloc_trim (s=s@entry=0) at malloc.c:4822
```

I would like to know the reason for this crash and how to avoid it.

I checked the man page for `malloc_trim()`, it does not look like it can cause a crash.

Comment: That is impossible to tell without code.

Comment: code? code? code?

Comment: Why are using `malloc_trim()`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the man page for `malloc_trim()`:

> **MALLOC_TRIM(3)                 Linux Programmer's Manual               MALLOC_TRIM(3)**
>
> **NAME**
>
> `malloc_trim` - release free memory from the top of the heap
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <malloc.h>
>
> int malloc_trim(size_t pad);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `malloc_trim()` function attempts to release free memory at the top of the heap (by calling `sbrk(2)` with a suitable argument).
>
> The `pad` argument specifies the amount of free space to leave untrimmed at the top of the heap.  If  this  argument is `0`, only the minimum amount of memory is maintained at the top of the heap (i.e., one page or less).  A nonzero argument can be used to maintain some trailing space at the top of the heap in order to allow future  allocation to be made without having to extend the heap with `sbrk(2)`.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `malloc_trim()` function returns `1` if memory was actually released back to the system, or `0` if it was not possible to release any memory.
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> No errors are defined.
>
> **CONFORMING TO**
>
> This function is a GNU extension.
>
> **NOTES**
>
> This function is automatically called by `free(3)` in certain circumstances; see the  discussion  of  `M_TOP_PAD`  and `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD` in `mallopt(3)`.
>
> This function cannot release free memory located at places other than the top of the heap.
>
> This function releases only memory in the main arena.

`0` is a perfectly fine argument for this GNU extended function.  The errors reported seem to indicate a corruption of the heap, possibly caused by your program before calling `malloc_trim()`.  These errors could be:

- modification of bytes beyond the end or before the beginning of an allocated block
- modification of a block after it has been freed
- multiple frees of the same block

You should investigate with memory tools such as valgrind to identify these problems.

Also note that `malloc_trim()` is not portable and of limited interest in practice as it only trims the legacy heap allocated with `sbrk()`.  Modern allocators use `mmap` to allocate different arenas and should handle the release of unused pages back to the OS automatically.